# send file from client to server C not working file_desc return -1 for unknown reason

Tags: c, unix, server, ftp, client

I have been trying to get this FTP client/ server to work together but its currently not playing friendly
Bits of code that I have tested and that I couldn't find to work have been commented but also some of these commented recv and write lines work but to make the over all problem simpler i have commented them out for the time being. The problem seems to be in the ConnectionHandler function under the `else if(strstr(client_request, "Put"))` line of code. i have currently got successful FTP from the server to the client but the client to server part I'm struggling to get to work any advice would be grateful.

I feel as though this line is the problem `file_desc = open(file_name, O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_WRONLY, 0777);` but i need to create the file to run to but file_desc returns -1 even though the file is created and I'm simply unable to determine why this is the case. Ultimately i may be overlooking something else.

**Server**

```
/*
 *  Compile & link  :   gcc server.c -lpthread -o server
 *  Execute         :   ./server
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/sendfile.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define SERVER_PORT 8080

void* ConnectionHandler(void* socket_desc);
char* GetFilenameFromRequest(char* request);
bool SendFileOverSocket(int socket_desc, char* file_name);
int readn(int fd, char *buf, int bufsize)
{
    short data_size; // sizeof (short) must be 2
    int n, nr, len;
    // check buffer size len
    if (bufsize < BUFSIZ)
        return (-3); // buffer too small
    // get the size of data sent to me
    if (read(fd, (char *) &data_size, 1) != 1)
        return (-1);

    if (read(fd, (char *) (&data_size)+1, 1) != 1) 
        return (-1);

    len = (int) ntohs(data_size); // convert to host byte order
    // read len number of bytes to buf
    for (n=0; n < len; n += nr) 
    {
        if ((nr = read(fd, buf+n, len-n)) <= 0)
            return (nr); // error in reading
    }
    return (len);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int     socket_desc, 
            socket_client, 
            *new_sock, 
            c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    struct  sockaddr_in server, 
                        client;

    // Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        perror("Could not create socket");
        return 1;
    }

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    if (bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Bind failed");
        return 1;
    }

    listen(socket_desc , 3);
    
    while (socket_client = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c))
    {
        pthread_t sniffer_thread;
        new_sock = malloc(1);
        *new_sock = socket_client;        
        pthread_create(&sniffer_thread, NULL,  ConnectionHandler, (void*) new_sock);
        pthread_join(sniffer_thread, NULL);
    }
     
    if (socket_client<0)
    {
        perror("Accept failed");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void *ConnectionHandler(void *socket_desc)
{
    int socket = *(int*)socket_desc;   
    char    server_response[BUFSIZ],
            client_request[BUFSIZ],
            file_name[BUFSIZ];
    
    recv(socket, client_request, BUFSIZ, 0);        //Wait at this point to recieve a message from the client
    if(strstr(client_request, "Get"))
    {
        perror("1");
        strcpy(file_name, GetFilenameFromRequest(client_request));

        // If requested file exists, notify the client and send it
        if (access(file_name, F_OK) != -1){

            perror("2");
            strcpy(server_response, "OK");
            write(socket, server_response, strlen(server_response));
            perror("3");
            SendFileOverSocket(socket, file_name);
            perror("4");
        }
        else {
            // Requested file does not exist, notify the client
            strcpy(server_response, "NO");
            write(socket, server_response, strlen(server_response)); 
        }
    }
    else if(strstr(client_request, "Put"))
    {
        char *data, reply_msg[BUFSIZ];
        char buff[BUFSIZ];
        int file_size, file_desc;
        perror("0.5");
        strcpy(file_name, GetFilenameFromRequest(client_request));
        perror("0.75");
        //recv(socket, reply_msg, 2, 0);    //Receive reply message from client if file exists

        //fprintf(stderr, "File was found = %s", reply_msg);
        //Create File
        perror("1");
        recv(socket, &file_size, sizeof(int), 0);
        perror("1.25");
        file_desc = open(file_name, O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_WRONLY, 0666);
        perror("1.5");
        int incomingSize;
        while((incomingSize = readn(socket, buff, sizeof(buff))) > 0)
        {
            perror("2 ");
            for(int i = 0; i <= sizeof(buff); i++)
            {
                buff[incomingSize] = '\0';
                write(file_desc, buff, sizeof(buff));
            }
        }
        perror("3");
        if(incomingSize < 0)
        {
            perror("Something went wrong connection broken");
            return; // connection broken down
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Connection terminated");
        }
        
        perror("4");
        close(socket);
        

        /*
        perror("1");
        data = malloc(BUFSIZ);
        file_desc = open(file_name, O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_WRONLY, 0777);

        perror("1.2");
        fprintf(stderr, "fileDesc = %d", file_desc);

        
        perror("1.5");
        strcpy(server_response, "OK");
        write(socket, server_response, strlen(server_response));
        perror("2");
        //recv(socket, &file_size, sizeof(int), 0);
        perror("3");
        //recv(socket, &file_size, sizeof(int), 0);
        file_size = BUFSIZ;
        perror("4");
        fprintf(stderr, "%d", file_size);
        recv(socket, data, file_size, 0);
        perror("5");
        write(file_desc, data, file_size);
        perror("6");
        close(file_desc);
        */
        /*// Start receiving file
        if (strcmp(reply_msg, "OK") == 0)   //Check that response is "OK"
        {
            
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Bad request\n");
        }   
        */
    }
    

    free(socket_desc);   
    return 0;
}

char* GetFilenameFromRequest(char* request)
{
    char *file_name = strchr(request, ' ');
    return file_name + 1;
}

bool SendFileOverSocket(int socket_desc, char* file_name)
{
    struct stat obj;
    int     file_desc,
            file_size;

    stat(file_name, &obj);
    file_desc = open(file_name, O_RDONLY);
    file_size = obj.st_size;
    send(socket_desc, &file_size, sizeof(int), 0);
    sendfile(socket_desc, file_desc, NULL, file_size);

    return true;
}
```

**Client**

```
/*
 *  Compile & link  :   gcc client.c -o client
 *  Execute         :   ./client
 *
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/sendfile.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define FILENAME    "a.txt"         //Possibly worth changing to make it more dynamic
                                    //Should consider overriding this with command line arguments if passed                                     
#define SERVER_IP   "127.0.0.1"     //Address of local host
#define SERVER_PORT     8080    


bool SendFileOverSocket(int socket_desc, char* file_name);


int writen(int fd, char *buf, int nbytes)
{
    short data_size = nbytes; // short must be two bytes long
    int n, nw;
    if (nbytes > BUFSIZ)
        return (-3); // too many bytes to send in one go
    // send the data size
    data_size = htons(data_size);
    if (write(fd, (char *) &data_size, 1) != 1) 
        return (-1);
    if (write(fd, (char *) (&data_size)+1, 1) != 1)
         return (-1);
    // send nbytes
    for (n=0; n<nbytes; n += nw) 
    {
        if ((nw = write(fd, buf+n, nbytes-n)) <= 0)
            return (nw); // write error
    }
    return (n);
}

int main(int argc , char **argv)
{
    int socket_desc;
    // Variables for the file being received
    int file_size, file_desc;

    struct  sockaddr_in server;
    char    request_msg[BUFSIZ],
            reply_msg[BUFSIZ],
            userCommand[BUFSIZ],
            userFileName[BUFSIZ],
            *data;

    
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        perror("Could not create socket");
        return 1;
    }

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVER_IP);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    // Connect to server
    if (connect(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Connection failed");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("------------Enter Command-----------\n");
    printf("Get, Put, Pwd, lpwd, dir, ldir, cd, lcd, quit\n");
    printf("------------------------------------\n");
    while(userCommand != "quit")
    {
        printf(">");
        fgets(userCommand, BUFSIZ, stdin);

        printf("User Command Variable = %s", userCommand);
        if(strstr(userCommand, "Get"))
        {
            char userFileName[BUFSIZ];
            // Get a file from server
            strcpy(request_msg, "Get ");                            //Copy message "Get " into variable request_msg
            printf("Enter the file name you would like to send.");
            scanf("%s", userFileName);
            strcat(request_msg, userFileName);                          //Add the file name to the end of the varaible that is now "Get "
            printf("1");
            write(socket_desc, request_msg, strlen(request_msg));   //Changing this to fwrite produces same results with more warnings
            printf("2");
            recv(socket_desc, reply_msg, 2, 0);                     //Wait here for response
            printf("3");
            // Start receiving file
            if (strcmp(reply_msg, "OK") == 0)   //Check that response is "OK"
            {
                printf("4");
                recv(socket_desc, &file_size, sizeof(int), 0);
                printf("5");
                data = malloc(file_size);
                file_desc = open(userFileName, O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_WRONLY, 0666);
                recv(socket_desc, data, file_size, 0);
                printf("6");
                write(file_desc, data, file_size);
                printf("7");
                close(file_desc);
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Bad request\n");
            }
        }
        else if(strstr(userCommand, "Put"))
        {
            char server_response[BUFSIZ], buff[BUFSIZ];
            struct stat obj;
            fprintf(stderr,"What is the file name you would like to send?\n");
            scanf("%s", userFileName);
            fprintf(stderr,"File name entered was: %s", userFileName);

            strcpy(request_msg, "Put ");                            //Copy message "Get " into variable request_msg
            strcat(request_msg, userFileName);                          //Add the file name to the end of the varaible that is now "Get "
            perror("1");
            write(socket_desc, request_msg, strlen(request_msg));   //Changing this to fwrite produces same results with more warnings
            perror("2");
            
            stat(userFileName, &obj);
            file_desc = open(userFileName, O_RDONLY);
            file_size = obj.st_size;

            perror("2.1");
            strcpy(reply_msg, "OK");
            perror("2.2");
            //write(socket_desc, reply_msg, strlen(reply_msg));
            perror("2.3");
            perror("2.4");
            perror("2.45");
            writen(socket_desc, buff, sizeof(buff));
            //SendFileOverSocket(socket_desc, userFileName);
            perror("3");
            close(socket_desc);

            /*if (access(userFileName + 1, F_OK) != -1)
            {
                
            }
            else {
                printf("File doesnt exist with access code %d\n", access(userFileName, F_OK));
                strcpy(reply_msg, "OK");
                write(socket, reply_msg, strlen(reply_msg));
            }*/
        }

    }
    
    return 0;
}

/*bool SendFileOverSocket(int socket_desc, char* file_name)
{
    struct stat obj;
    int     file_desc,
            file_size;
    
    stat(file_name, &obj);
    file_desc = open(file_name, O_RDONLY);
    file_size = obj.st_size;
    printf("2.5");
    printf("%s", file_name);
    //send(socket_desc, &file_size, sizeof(int), 0);
    printf("2.6");
    perror("Pre");
    sendfile(socket_desc, file_desc, NULL, file_size);
    perror("sendfile");
    printf("2.7");

    return true;
}*/
```

Comment: Cal `perror` to get a more specific error msg.

Comment: You shouldn't assume that a single call to `recv()` will return the entire file. You need to keep reading in a loop until you get everything. Which means you need to design a protocol to tell when you've reached the end of the file.

Comment: You MUST correctly, and completely, handle the results reurned from system calls, (esp 'recv', as Barmar says above).  You cannot ignore them.  The result returned from recv() is the ONLY way to determine how many bytes have been read into the buffer.  Design your code so that, even if recv() always returns '1' after a successful read, it will still work correctly.

Comment: So ive updated the code so show perrors and everything but I am currently getting everything successful but I don't get the results I'm after.